# Is there a way to redirect a NuxtJs application using Express server?

Tags: express, nuxt.js

I have a NuxtJs application initialized with Express server using `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`. It is set for server-side rendering.

Express has access to NuxtJs middleware like so. ( Which comes by default when Nuxt app is created )

```
app.use(nuxt.render)
```

Now I have created a different route file in server side that handles API routes. This route works as I can access data using Axios. I have added this route right before the above code, like this. ( API routes don't work if it is added after )

```
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)
app.use(nuxt.render)
```

There is a route where, after some operation, I need to redirect the application to another page. I tried using `res.redirect('/some-route')`, which is an Express way for redirection but that didn't work.

Am I missing something here? Is there some other way we do redirection from server side in Nuxt application that I'm totally unaware of?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: You could use a middleware. In the middleware, use context api for redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the way to redirect from the back-end.

```js
res.writeHead(301, { Location: url })
res.end()
```

[Here is the link](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1592#issuecomment-328756549) to Nuxt GitHub issue comment for detailed example using server middleware.

Alternatively, you could respond with desired value to the font-end and based on the value received, you can re-direct from the front-end.